# how to call similar POST variables, like city1 city2 in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

Just have simple question. I have PHP page with ajax, that generates some forms. Those forms could be submitted with ajax. the data, that gonna be send to PHP action script, could be either `$POST['city0']` or `$POST['city5']` or `$POST['city20']` and etc..

So how can I have access to this POST data? is that something like :

```
$city = POST['city[..]'] ;
```

possible?   whats is the right syntax?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried yet. Few years ago i've seen the script with these things, but cant remember the right sintax

Comment: How does your form look? How do you submit it via AJAX? Please share some of your code with us :)

Comment: @Madara Uchiha I posted it here [link](http://pastebin.com/UA0gepMC), because my low reputation wont let me answer. The Ajax is not included there to simplify the code

Answer (score 4):

If you are not concerned with the index of the items in the array you can go with this simple array syntax:

```
<form name="example" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="city[]">
  <input type="text" name="city[]">
  <input type="text" name="city[]">
</form>
```

Or you can give them numbered indexes:

```
<form name="example" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="city[15]">
  <input type="text" name="city[7]">
  <input type="text" name="city[203]">
</form>
```

Or string indexes:

```
<form name="example" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="city[ny]">
  <input type="text" name="city[ca]">
  <input type="text" name="city[or]">
</form>
```

Whatever form you choose you will access by:

```
$myVar = $_POST['city'][$index];
```

And, as always, `print_r()` is your friend because it will show you the structure of your data if you don't know or can't remember:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Will give you something like:

```
Array
(
    [city] => Array
        (
            [ny] => one
            [ca] => two
            [or] => three
        )
)
```

Comment: ok, ill explain more. I have a script -  there is multiply zipcodes input. The script will look up for respective cities of those zips and build another page, where those cities will be grouped by states to different forms. So name of those forms must be different. as well checkboxes for cities must be different because of toggleAll. http://s21.postimg.org/g05uqi36v/cities.jpg

Comment: @user2437063 I honestly don't see how that changes anything.

Comment: i cant post the solution here, so i post it on pastebin http://pastebin.com/1GFCB3dR

Comment: @user2437063 If it works, it works. You could also do `name="city[state][]"` which will yield something like `$_POST[city][state][$index]`.

Answer (score 3):

Set the input name attribute as `name="city[]"`, that way `$_POST['city']` will be an array.

Comment: no, those are already arrays. like form#1: state CA, cities array, form#2: state NY, cities array. And could be send one by one only

Comment: @user2437063: Why one by one? Nested arrays are very possible. Where'd you get stuck?

Comment: i stuck with this: $_POST['city0'] = "Hello world";
echo $_POST["city[..]"]; or $_POST["city[i]"] or any other way. because i dont know how many elements could be

Answer (score 1):

Doing it like this you will have to try every single possibility from `city0` to `cityN`.

I suggest you name your parameters like this: `city[X]` where X is the number.

Then you can simply cycle through all the values with a foreach like this:

```
foreach($_POST['city'] as $key => $city) "city[" . $key . "] = " . $city;
```

Comment: nb you don't need the number

Comment: it looks like he does, therefore i included it.

Comment: @Prisoner: If the numbers mean something (for instance, city IDs), you most certainly do. It won't hurt the ability to loop though the array, even if you give them odd keys.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I was merely noting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `$_POST["city".(string)0];` to get them.

Or loop through them with

```
for( $i=0; $i != 5; $i++ ){
    echo $_POST["city".$i];
}
```

If you can modify your forms thought, @Danijel's answer is the best, passing the data back as an array.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this as it's the only correct answer so far ;)

Comment: No need for (string), let's start with that, when you concatenate you automatically convert to string. Second, if you need a numbered variable, you need an array. It's not that your answer isn't technically correct, it's not helpful. Side-note, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: I've removed the (string) (thanks for that). The OP is asking to get variables called $_POST['city0'] and $_POST['city1'], this does what he/she wants.

Comment: Heard of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What OP wants isn't always the best, sometimes there are better alternatives which are also easy to implement (for instance, asking someone to move immediately to PDO from mysql_* is probably too much to ask, but moving from `$varN` to `$var[N]`? Nothing wrong with that).

Comment: i couldn't know which city[1-1000] will come and how many elements could be. I wish, i can write is like reg ext $_POST["city[0-9]{1,}"], but of course its not possible..

Comment: Could you not just loop thought the possibilities (1-1000), and using `isset()` to determine which is set? Then possibly put the 'set' ones into another array, then you'll know that array contains data which you can work with?

Comment: now i get it. I should not use city1, city2, but something like city_.$state. And send $_POST['state'] along with $_POST['city_ca'] and get it as $state = $_POST['state']; echo $_POST['city_'.$state];

Answer (score 0):

I was really thinking, that there in PHP is it possible to use "bash like" style, similar to this - `touch file{1..3} && rm file{1..3}`
Finally I gave up and changed checkboxes arrays and form names to more specified. 
And to give a clue to the receiving PHP script.
Before it was:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($states as $state){
   echo "<form id=\"form" . $counter . "\">";

// Here we do MySQL request and pulling out cities 
// where state=$state to $cities array... 
// Then unpack em as a check-boxes:  

 foreach($cities as $city){
      echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"city" . $counter . "[]\" ...

  ...
      $counter++;
 }
```

and now i've changed it to:

```
foreach ($states as $state){
  echo "<form id=\"form_" . $state . "\">";

// Here we do MySQL request and pulling out cities
// where state=$state to $cities checkbox array...
//  Then unpack em as a check-boxes:  

foreach($cities as $city){
   echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"city_" . $state . "[]\" ...

  ...      
   echo "<input type=hidden name=state value=".$state.">";....
```

Because $state has no duplicates by default, so all generated elements will have their own unique names
And now I can easily have access to `$_POST['city_?']`:

```
$state = $_POST['state'];
echo $_POST['city_'.$state];
```

and so on.. And thank you everyone, who have helped me out here